# Reference Error: array value is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm working with a Node web app where I'm passing data through from the server to the client.  Here's the route in question:

```
router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
Player.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPlayer){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        let years = foundPlayer.season.map(({
            grade}) => grade);

        res.render("players/show", {player: foundPlayer, yearTotals: years });
    }
});
```

});

I'm passing through specific information about a `player` from Mongo after creating a variable to store a map of `years`.  Here's the script tag from the EJS template that I'm working with:

```
    let xAxis = [<%= yearTotals %>];
```

Viewing the code in the Chrome console shows this:

```
let xAxis = [Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior]
```

So the values are successfully passed through; however, I'm hit with this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Freshman is not defined
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are those expected to be strings?  Cause they do not have quotes around them if so.

Comment: @Taplar - yes they are, what would be the appropriate method of converting the values to strings?

Comment: Probably need to look into your options around `let xAxis = [<%= yearTotals %>];` to see what is available to make sure the strings have quotes around them

Comment: `let xAxis = <% JSON.stringify(yearTotals) %>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

First, I added JSON.stringify to the array like so:

```
let xAxis = <% JSON.stringify(yearTotals) %>
```

That returned the `&#34` encoding for the quotations.  The below solved my problem:

```
let xAxis = <%- JSON.stringify(yearTotals) %>;
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!